# download large file using PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

I would like to download large file (12Gb) using PnP since in PnP there is a nice auth method `UseWebLogin`

However from [this issue](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/1797) it looks like that it is not supported. Can I somehow overcome this limitation or is there any alternative method to download a file while authenticate using Windows account (with MFA)

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint online, **Downloads** are subject to the following limits: individual file size limit: 10GB; total zip file size limit: 20GB; total number of files limit: 10,000; folder size limit: 200 files.

Try to use PowerShell CSOM to download large files:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/03/sharepoint-online-download-all-files-from-document-library-using-powershell.html

Alternative to connect to SharePoint Online using PowerShell with MFA(please refer to CSOM PowerShell Script with MFA part)

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/08/connect-sharepoint-online-powershell-using-mfa.html